# Angular 12/rxjs 7/angularfire: async token interceptor with deprecated toPromise

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire, rxjs6

I am using angularfire with and auth interceptor adding a token to every request. This interceptor requires an async call as the token might requires a refresh.

With an update to rxjs 7, my async tokenHandler now faces two issues:

- the .toPromise() is depcrated
- the async tokenHandler may returns undefined (Type 'HttpEvent | undefined' is not assignable to type 'HttpEvent')

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    const fireUser = this.auth.fireAuthUser.value;

    if (fireUser) {
      // convert promise to observable using 'from' operator
      return from(this.tokenHandler(request, next, fireUser));
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }

  async tokenHandler(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler, currentUser: firebase.User): Promise<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const authToken = await currentUser.getIdToken().then();

    if (authToken) {
      request = request.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + authToken } });
    }

    return next.handle(request).toPromise();
  }
}
```

Could you advise me on how to rewrite the async tokenHandler?

Comment: I haven't used promises in a while. is `.then()` without any arguments a no-op (does nothing) or does it always return `undefined`? Never seen that idiom before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stream$.toPromise()` is most semantically similar to the new `lastValueFrom(stream$)` except:

The type information of toPromise **was** wrong.

When the source Observable completed without ever emitting a single value - it resolved with undefined. It should reject in that case, but it doesn't. lastValueFrom and firstValueFrom will both reject in this case.

Therefore, you can fix this with `lastValueFrom` or `firstValueFrom`.

```ts
async tokenHandler(
  request: HttpRequest<any>, 
  next: HttpHandler, 
  currentUser: firebase.User
): Promise<HttpEvent<any>> {
  const authToken = await currentUser.getIdToken();

  if (authToken) {
    request = request.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + authToken } });
  }

  return lastValueFrom(next.handle(request));
}
```

Comment: topromise has been deprecate. https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise